# ReCaptcha for .Net 2.0 conflicting with other forms on site

Tags: .net-2.0, recaptcha, login-control

I've read and re-read multiple posts on this site and others that seem to touch on a similar topic but none of the suggested fixes work for me.

Asp.net 2.0 site, has Master pages and multiple user controls. I have a login user control that allows a user to login / register on the site. I've also an entirely separate control with a form that a user can fill out to pay money. I added a reCaptcha (the version compatible with .net 2.0) to this form and it works.

However, once I add it ANYWHERE on the site I can no longer login, the login form submits but just refreshes with no action taken, login details are correct.

I thought it was to do with Validation groups so I added (via a custom validator) a validation group to the reCaptcha (a thread on this site suggested that solution) - this didn't work, same problem.

I then changed the login control to a template so I could set it's Validation Group manually as I saw this suggested here as well - again didn't work - same refresh issue.

I'm at a loss, as soon as I add the usercontrol that contains the recaptcha anywhere on my site, my login ceases to work.

I can't upgrade to .net 3.5 + as the site is fully built  and functional already.

Can anyone suggest anything that might make these two play nicely together?

Answer (score 0):

Is it maybe because the recapctha (when not filled correctly) makes your page not valid? What happens when you provide correct login details and also correctly fill the recaptcha form?

Comment: That's the weird thing, the recaptcha is not on or anywhere near the login page. It lives on one user control which isn't loaded when the login control is loaded.

It's related to the recaptcha not being valid alright but the problem is that it's not actually on the login page nor is it required there, it's in its own separate user control for use elsewhere on the site but is interfering somehow.

Comment: Basically, you should debug your login code and see what and why happens. Your said: "the login form submits but just refreshes with no action taken" - this sounds like a validation fail.

Comment: Was a conflict with the catcha as both controls were being loaded. I'm not sure why adding a validationgroup didn't solve the problem (I added one yesterday with no luck) but in any case dynamically loading the control with the catcha in it sorted the problem for now.Thanks